# How to login into an application with login credentials using guzzlehttp?

Tags: php, guzzle6, guzzle

How to login into an application with login credentials using guzzlehttp ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error are you facing? have you tried any code?

Answer (score 0):

Login into your application should be as straightforward as doing a post request to the correct endpoint with correct credentials.

eg from the docs at http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', [
    'form_params' => [
        'field_name' => 'abc',
        'other_field' => '123',
        'nested_field' => [
            'nested' => 'hello'
        ]
    ] ]);
```

However most likely the application is using cookies to maintain state. By default Guzzle doesn't store cookies, but you can enable this behaviour with the cookie plugin. http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/plugins/cookie-plugin.html

Once this is enabled you just need an initial request to login to the application and initiate the session. Your second call should happen as a logged in user.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your fast reply. i tried like how you said  in above code but i ended in an error "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"   what to do now?

Comment: $response = $client->request('POST', $login_url,$post_data);

Comment: $response = $client->request('POST', $login_url,$post_data);

Comment: $response = $client->request('POST', $login_url,$post_data); this is my code but i am not login, where i am missing ?  thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you are using a self signed certificate... Try to disable the check with: $client->setDefaultOption('verify', false); Remember to enable it in production;-)